# Свой атрибут/описание для public поля класса

Tags: c#, рефлексия, атрибуты

Есть у меня классы, у них открытые переменные. Я через reflection добираюсь до их значений для последующего отображения/изменения.

По умолчанию - есть некоторый диапазон для изменения, условно -+20%.

Но для некоторых переменных есть свои особенности: -10%/+20% или 0..100. Это исключения, они не многочисленны, но они есть.

Мне хочется, когда буду перебирать переменные, чтобы можно было прямо в коде задать для переменной свой атрибут или не знаю как это называется - описание, которое я мог бы пропарсить:

```
public int Length;

// Min: 0. Max: 100
public int Size;

[Range:20%]
public int Weight;
```

Чтобы было более наглядно: у Unity3D есть [HideInInspector](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/HideInInspector.html). Что-то похожее хочу сделать, но более информативно.

Comment: Сделайте аттрибут, который в конструкторе `string` принимает, а потом анализируйте те `property`, которые им помечены.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте для этого кастомные классы атрибутов, они для того и созданы, чтобы предоставлять мета-информацию об объектах в отражениях.

Например, вот атрибут, позволяющий задавать диапазон для полей:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
class RangeAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Percent { get; set; }

    public RangeAttribute (int percent)
    {
        Percent = percent;
    }
}
```

Задавать значение диапазона на поле можно так:

```
class Foo
{
    [Range(20)]
    public int Bar;
}
```

Ну а дальше — отражения:

```
FieldInfo barField = typeof(Foo).GetField("Bar");
RangeAttribute barRange = barField.GetCustomAttribute<RangeAttribute>();
int range = barRange != null ? barRange.Percent : 20;
var foo = new Foo();
barField.SetValue(foo, 10);
```

См.:

- [Attributes Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa288454.aspx) (MSDN)
- [Writing Custom Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/84c42s56.aspx) (MSDN)
- [Creating Custom Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/sw480ze8.aspx) (MSDN)

Comment: На всякий случай - в некоторых проектах можно использовать структуру Unit, для хранения значения в Range-аттрибуте, т.к. она позволяет задать значение px, %, cm, mm https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.unit(v=vs.110).aspx